# Loading a file in spark in standalone cluster

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a four node spark cluster . One node is both master and slave, other three slave node. I have written a sample application which load file and created a data frame and running some spark SQL. When i am submitting the application like below from master node , it is producing output:-

```
./spark-submit /root/sample.py
```

But When i am submitting with master like below , it says "File does not exists error.

```
./spark-submit  --master spark://<IP>:PORTNO  /root/sample.py
```

I am creating an RDD from sample text file :-

```
lines = sc.textFile("/root/testsql.txt");
```

Do i need to copy the file to all the nodes?? How it will work for the production systems , eg. if have to process some CDRS , where should i receive these CDRS .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right, it is not able to read that file, because it doesn't exist on your server.

You need to make sure that file is accessible via same url/path to all the nodes of spark.

That is where distributed file system like hdfs makes thing little easier, but you can do it even without them.

When you submit spark job to master, master will allocate the required executors and workers. Each of them will try to parallelize the task, which is what sc.textFile is telling it to do.
So, the file path needs to be accessible from all nodes.

You can either mount the file on all nodes at same location, or instead use a url based location to read the file. Basic thing is file needs to be available and readable from all nodes.

Comment: ..I am bit confused ..if i have one file of 1000 lines and i will copy it to all locations..do all slaves work on the same file?? How load is balanced between them...Also if i have a shared location where i will keep 100 CDR files..how these files will be distributed among slaves ??

Comment: Well, i have never copied a file to every node, ideally you should make same file accessible to all the node, through way i explained before. Regarding distributing, it works on partition. Basically think it this way, if there are 1000 lines in the file, and you explicitly say lines.repartition(10). It will create 10 parallel partition of 100 lines each and with 4 workers process 4 of them at one time. If you don't specify partition, it uses it's internal algorithm to compute number of partition.